# How to dynamically use ng-for to get input boxes and checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript

This is angular app. My requirement is :upon the number entered inside  input box (record.accountRoles, shown below), I want elements inside div to be repeated.

```
<!-- input box -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="name">Enter the number of accounts</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record.accountRoles" name="accountsRoles" required>
 </div>


<!-- div elements that must be repeated -->
 <div *ngFor="let i of record.accountRoles.length">
   <label for="name">AccountId</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record.roles[i].accountid" name="accountid" required> 

    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "record.roles[i].role"> 
     <label>IT Admin</label> 
    </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```

This is how record variable is initialized

```
 record = {firstName:null,lastName:null,emailAddress:null,accountRoles:null,roles:[{accountid:null,role:null}]};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html to:

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Enter the number of accounts</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="record.accountRoles" (change)="updateAccounts()"name="accountsRoles" required>
     </div>


    <!-- div elements that must be repeated -->
     <div *ngFor="let item of record.roles">
       <label for="name">AccountId</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.accountid" name="accountid" required> 
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "item.role"> 
             <label>IT Admin</label> 
            </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
```

If you need the index for something use:

```
*ngFor="let item of record.accountRoles; let i = index"
```

Change your component to:

```
   record = {firstName:null,lastName:null,emailAddress:null,accountRoles:1,roles:[{accountid:null,role:null}]};

updateAccounts () {
  this.record.roles = [];

  for(let i = 0 ; i< this.record.accountRoles; i++)
    this.record.roles.push({accountid:null,role:null}); 
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzuc9h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi Miguel, I made the change in HTML but I don't see div elements shown dynamically. Also when I do {{record.accountsRoles}} I see number entered inside input box

Comment: Hi, I changed my answer.

Comment: How do I retrieve this field value <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.accountid" name="accountid" required> (inside div)

Comment: I tried, this.record.roles[1].accountid; doesn't print value

Comment: Hi, i update my sample and now i show the json value in html, if you fill the accountid the 'record' is change.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzuc9h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html